# C#: How do i access data from a deserialized xml-file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've set up a xml-serialization / deserialization for saving data in my application. I can deserialize non-array elements, but when i deserialize an array it is empty. I have a hunch that the problem is in the set portion of the property im trying to serialize/deserialize.

**First the class i'm trying to serialize:**

```
namespace kineticMold
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Config
    {
        public Config() { }
        public string ComPort
        {
            get
            {
                return comPort;
            }
            set
            {
                comPort = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlArrayItem("recentFile")]
        public string[] LastOpen
        {

            get
            {
                return lastOpen;
            }
            set
            {

                    ArrayList holderList = new ArrayList();

                    holderList.Add(value);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {

                        holderList.Add(lastOpen[i]);

                    }

                    lastOpen = (string[])lastOpen.ToArray<string>();



            }
        }

        private string comPort;
        private string[] lastOpen = new string[5];


    }
}
```

**The result of the serialization:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ComPort>COM12</ComPort> 
    <LastOpen>
       <recentFile>test.xml</recentFile> 
       <recentFile xsi:nil="true" /> 
       <recentFile xsi:nil="true" /> 
       <recentFile xsi:nil="true" /> 
       <recentFile xsi:nil="true" /> 
    </LastOpen>
</Config>
```

**The code for deserialization:**

```
_cf = new Config();
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));

            if (File.Exists(settings_filepath))
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@settings_filepath, FileMode.Open);
                _cf = (Config)ser.Deserialize(fs);
                fs.Close();
            }
```

**The code for reading the deserialized data:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _cf.LastOpen.Length; i++)
            {

                if (_cf.LastOpen[i] != null)
                {
                    toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(_cf.LastOpen[i]);

                    recentState = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a *List<String>* instead?

Comment: @Sotmenet - Are lists better suited for serialization? Haven't tried it yet. Tried an Arraylist, but that failed miserably.

Comment: No, it does not make a difference, but it could be more usable for you as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
lastOpen = (string[])lastOpen.ToArray<string>();
```

Do you mean `holderList` here (on the right hand side)?

It isn't *entirely* clear which data you want, but you don't currently keep any of the items from `value` beyond the setter. Also, `ArrayList` is largely redundant here; it could be a `List<string>` perhaps?

Of course, even simpler:

```
private readonly List<string> lastOpen = new List<string>();
[XmlArrayItem("recentFile")]
public List<string> LastOpen {get {return lastOpen;}}
```

(and let the *calling* code worry about how many items to keep in there)

Comment: Hi Marc. I changed my code, still using Array, but letting the calling code worry about how many items to keep there, and changing the contents when necessary did the trick, thanks.